# Building Deb Package Error

Tags: debian, deb

This is my first time building a deb package. I am following Debian documentation on getting this started and am running into an error. Here is what my debian/rules file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@
        override_dh_install
        dh_install foo/ bar/
```

I proceed forth with running the command to build the package:

`fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -F`

And run into this error:

```
    dpkg-buildpackage: source package blah
    dpkg-buildpackage: source version 3.0
    dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution UNRELEASED
    dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by root <root@x.x.x.x>
    dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
     dpkg-source --before-build blah-3.0
     debian/rules clean
    dh clean
       dh_testdir
       dh_auto_clean
       dh_clean
    override_dh_install
make: override_dh_install: Command not found
debian/rules:3: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to what I am doing wrong? Let me know if you need more info.

UPDATE: The way I have my directories structured is this:

```
├── debian
│   ├── changelog
│   ├── compat
│   ├── control
│   ├── dsps.dirs
│   ├── rules
│   └── sources
│       └── format
|__ blah-3.0
    |_ foo
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you did: where is that first script? Is it in a file? What name?

Comment: I updated my question. Hope this gives you more info

Comment: Did @StephenKitt's answer not solve this for you? What happens when you fix the error he points out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`override_dh_install` is a target, your `debian/rules` file should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_install:
        dh_install foo/ bar/
```

Assuming you’re building `blah-3.0`, the `debian` directory needs to be a subdirectory of `blah-3.0`.

Comment: I have debian as the subdirectory

Comment: I need to update my question and correct the dir structure.. but debian is a subdirectory

Comment: OK, so if you change your `debian/rules` as indicated the build should work better.

Comment: Sorry, you missunderstood. My directory structure already is how you mentioned. But the way its set up in my question is not valid.

Comment: Forget about the folder layout and read the first part of my answer: your `override_dh_install` line is wrong, look at how I’ve written it.

Comment: that seemed to have worked. Thanks for the help!